# What is this under the steel front door?

Tags: insulation, front-door

I assume this is a type of insulation. It tore off a bit when I removed the trim board while redoing floors. Before I put back the trim should I repair the insulation? Is there a product that can be applied with a caulk gun or should I use a small strip of styrofoam insulation?

[image]

Comment: Looks to me as though you have a plastic shim on top of a wood shim, with spray-foam [like this](http://greatstuff.dow.com/product/gaps-and-cracks.htm) on either side.

Comment: Agree totally with @brhans.  Picture is so close up tho, I'm not sure what you "tore off" and I can't tell what you want to replace?  The insulation foam  looks fine?

Comment: On the left side of the picture there's a bit of a depression. It sounds like you guys think it's a spray foam. The depression there was left because the rest stayed attached to the trim. I guess my biggest concern is whether this has anything to do with keeping water out but my sense is that's it's strictly insulation

Comment: Assuming we're looking at the interior side, then no the foam is not intended to keep water out (at least not by itself). If there's any similar gap on the outside then it should be properly caulked. I wouldn't worry about that little bit missing on the inside - the trim you pulled off was probably attached when the foam was still 'wet' and so it stuck (and that stuff really does stick ...).